# SQL Report Builder 3.0.Grouping Data from Dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Good day Everybody.

I am working on Sql Report Builder 3.0. I have a dataset with X records. From the data set i Supposed to display one or more table based on Some conditions. How can i do that..? I dint get solution from Google. Pls help me in this..

### Scenario:

Let say I have 4 Records in Dataset.

---

**OrderNo *_*__ Product *_*__ DeliveryDate *_*_____Address**

11223 ---------- Prod1 ----------20-Sep-2013 ---------- 31, Woodlands drive

11223 ---------- Prod2 ----------20-Sep-2013 ---------- 31, Woodlands drive

23688 ---------- Prod1 ----------20-Sep-2013 ---------- 227, North Avenue

23688 ---------- Prod2 ----------20-Sep-2013 ---------- 227, North Avenue

I want to display my report as follows,

### **Address:** 31, Woodlands drive

### Order_No ---------- Product

112233 ---------- Prod1
112233 ---------- Prod2

.
.
.

### Address: 227, North Avenue

### Order_No.......Product

236882 ---------- Prod1
236882 ---------- Prod2

--
Thanks,
Shami

Answer (score 0):

Set up a standard SSRS Table, then add a **Row Group** grouped by `Address`. Make sure to include a **Group Header** row.

You may need to create the left-most column that gets added by default when you add a Row Group.

Add another Group Header row.

In the first Group Header row, set a TextBox to display the `Address` field.

In the second Group Header row, type the column header details in the Textboxes.

In the detail row that was created with the table, add the `OrderNo` and `Product` fields.

See [Adding a Table to the Report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ddf2914-bcdd-427d-8cba-0ccb8342f819%28v=sql.105%29) and [Adding Grouping and Totals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3d61228-2aa4-42cc-955e-602dbf3406a7%28v=sql.105%29).